# d3js зеркальное масштабирование на двух svg элементах

Tags: d3.js

Отобразил два круга на различных svg. Хочу чтобы при перемещении/масштабировании одного объекта второй зеркально менялся. В d3 до 3.5.17 версии все работает прекрасно

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<div>
  <svg>
    </svg>
  <svg>
    </svg>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var parentHandler = function() {

    d3.selectAll('svg').each(function() {
      d3.select(this).select('circle').attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });


  };

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", parentHandler);
  var svgEvent = d3.selectAll('svg').each(function() {

    var svg = d3.select(this)
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 200);

    var circle = svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 30)
      .attr("cy", 30)
      .attr("r", 20)
      .style("fill", "#0f0")

    svg.call(zoom);
  });
</script>
```

начиная с 4.0.0 версии после перемещения/масштабирования одного круга перехожу на второй, чтобы тоже сделать изменения, то восстанавливаются первоначальные значения трансформации

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<div>
  <svg>
    </svg>
  <svg>
    </svg>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var parentHandler = function() {


    d3.selectAll('svg').each(function() {
      d3.select(this).select('circle').attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });


  };
  var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", parentHandler);

  var svgEvent = d3.selectAll('svg').each(function() {

    var svg = d3.select(this)
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 200);

    var circle = svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 30)
      .attr("cy", 30)
      .attr("r", 20)
      .style("fill", "#0f0")

    svg.call(zoom);
  });
</script>
```

Выходит, что для каждого svg используется свой объект трансформации... Как сделать так, чтобы поведение в пятой версии было аналогично поведению в третьей?

Comment: Если кому то пригодится, то решение нашел [здесь](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/_36l7uHNYsQ)